# Another this issue in javascript. Why is it undefined?

Tags: jquery

I have this class

```
 `use strict`

class CommentsController {
  constructor() {
    this.$addCommentForm = $('.add-comment')
    this.$addCommentButton = $('.add-comment input[type=submit]')
  }

  init() {
    this.addDefaultComments();
  }

  renderComment(comment, imageId) {
    let image = Image.all[imageId]
    image.comments.push(comment)
    $('#images').find(`ul[data-id=${imageId}] ul#comments-${imageId}`).append(`<li>${comment.commentContent}</li>\n`);
  }

  addDefaultComments() {
    debugger;
    $('.image').each((index, image) => {
      debugger;
      Comment.defaults.forEach((comment) => {
        // trying to call renderComment but I need access to the instance of the CommentsController
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The problem is that at the first debugger, I have access to the instance of this CommentsController. However, at the second debugger, I no longer have access to this instance of the controller even though I'm using an arrow function which should set `this` to be whatever value `this` is in the calling context. What is going on?

This is my html and libraries:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Flatstagram</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
  <script src="lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/underscore.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src/models/image.js"></script>
  <script src="src/models/comment.js"></script>
  <script src="src/controllers/images.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="src/controllers/comments.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>my image list</h1>

    <section id="images"></section>

  </div><!-- #wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Also, strangely, I don't have access to image and index at this debugger. Anyone know why?

```
addDefaultComments() {
    $('.image').each((index, image) => {
      Comment.defaults.forEach((comment) => {
        debugger;
        $('#images').find(`ul[data-id=${imageId}] ul#comments-${imageId}`).append(`<li>${comment.commentContent}</li>\n`);
      })
    })
  }
```

Should I have access to image and index in this nested for loop?

Comment: Nope, this is not possible what you are describing. You have something else affecting.

Comment: really? Any ideas what it couldbe?

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (emphasis mine):

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. **More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.**

`.each` is setting the value of `this` to the respective element in the current iteration.

In this case it may be necessary to cache a reference to the original `this`, or use a different method of iteration (like using `.toArray()` first and iterating over that.